# Can I edit bootstrap modal without using JS/Ajax?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am basically performing CRUD operation, in which I'm adding the data from modal which successfully added as well as fetching successfully but I want to edit there is a problem to get the id. I want to do this without using JS/AJAX, is it possible to edit the record in a bootstrap modal?

---

**list page start**, where data fetching from DB

```
<div class="table-responsive table-responsive-data2">
                    <table class="table table-data2">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="bg bg-success">
                                <th class="text-center">Sr#</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Room Name</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>';
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            $sql    = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM rooms");
            $srno = 0;
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            while($values = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            $srno++;
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            echo '
                            <tr class="tr-shadow">
                                <td>'.$srno.'</td>
                                <td>'.$values['room_name'].'</td>
                                <td>';
                                    if($values['room_status'] == 1)
                                    {
                                        echo'<span class="status bg bg-info">Active</span>';
                                    }
                                    else if($values['room_status'] == 2){
                                        echo'<span class="status bg bg-danger">Inactive</span>';
                                    }
                                    echo "id:".$id = $values['room_id'];
                                echo'
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="id" value="'.$values['room_id'].'">
                                    <div class="table-data-feature">
                                        <button class="item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update_room" data-id="'.$values['room_id'].'">
                                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i>
                                        </button>
            </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="spacer"></tr>';
                        }
                        echo'
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>
```

**list page end**

---

### **Modal start**, to edit the record

```
 <?php
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    $sql    = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room_id ='".$_GET['id']."'");
    $srno = 0;
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    ($values = mysqli_fetch_array($sql));
    echo'
    <div class="modal fade" id="update_room" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mediumModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg bg-success">
                    <h4 class="modal-title  text-white" id="mediumModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Room </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close  text-white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" > 
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body mt-lg">
                    <form action="#" class="form-horizontal" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                        <input type="text" name="room_id" id="room_id" value="id:'.$_GET['id'].'">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label class="control-label">Room Name <span class="required">*</span></label>  
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="room_name" value="'.$values['room_name'].'"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" >
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label class="control-label">Status <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                <div class="radio-inline">                                   
                                    <input type="radio" name="room_status" value="1" ';
                                    if($values['room_status'] == 1) 
                                    {echo'checked'; }echo'>
                                    <label for="">Active</label>
                                    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                    <input type="radio" name="room_status" value="2" '; if($values['room_status'] == 2) {echo'checked'; }echo'>
                                    <label for="">Inactive</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit_room">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ';
    ?>
```

**modal end**

Comment: @Dharman still my question is same, Can I edit bootstrap modal without using JS?

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you don't want to use ajax you have to submit a form to your bootstrap modal data Into a page and get them with get or post method and include them in php.
Like THis:
list page:

```
<form method="post" action="modal.php">
 <!-- Your List page code --->
 <!-- Input for your data --->
 <input name="data">
 <!-- a submit button --->
 <button type="submit">submit</buttton>
</form>
```

modal Page:

```
//get data from list page
$data = $_POST["data"];
//Your Codes and data in your modal body
```

Comment: These are my awnser of I undrestood.